# Applying Filter nav_menu_css_class to Custom Walker_Nav_Menu class

Tags: php, wordpress

Below is a filter that is applied for custom post types "portfolio".. it removed active class from "Blog" menu, and highlight a menu with ID 123, it works perfectly.. it highlight my menu with ID 123 that is "Portfolio", but it only applied to native main navigation, I mean I have 2 different menus one is made with custom Walker_Nav_Menu, it doesn't get applied to that...

so if I add this 'walker' => new my_walker() to the my code, it doesn't apply the following filter but otherwise it works perfectly.. Can anyone please tell me how can I apply this to a custom walker class at the same time ?.. thanks..

```
 function remove_parent_classes($class)
     {
       // check for current page classes, return false if they exist.
        return ($class == 'current_page_item' || $class ==      'current_page_parent' || $class == 'current_page_ancestor'  || $class == 'current-menu-item') ? FALSE : TRUE;
     }

     function add_class_to_wp_nav_menu($classes)
     {
          switch (get_post_type())
          {
            case 'portfolio':
                // we're viewing a custom post type, so remove the 'current_page_xxx and current-menu-item' from all menu items.
                $classes = array_filter($classes, "remove_parent_classes");

                // add the current page class to a specific menu item (replace ###).
                if (in_array('menu-item-123', $classes))
                {
                   $classes[] = 'current_page_parent';
                }
                break;

           // add more cases if necessary and/or a default
          }
         return $classes;
     }
     add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'add_class_to_wp_nav_menu');
```

Comment: can you post the `start_el` method code of your custom walker?

Comment: thanks fd7... below is my el code..

Comment: its here.. cant post in my reply.. http://pastebin.com/Lb8x53T8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `$item` argument:

```
function add_class_to_wp_nav_menu($classes, $item)
{
    switch (get_post_type($item->ID))
    {
        case 'portfolio':
            $classes = array_filter($classes, "remove_parent_classes");

            if (123 == $item->ID)
            {
                $classes[] = 'current_page_parent';
            }
            break;
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'add_class_to_wp_nav_menu', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks d79.. it worked I only had to change this part to make it work: switch (get_post_type()), it doesnt work with $item->ID.... THANKS A LOT...